# Import private SSH key to new client machine

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

First of all this is *not* a question ultimately about copying a public SSH key to a server's authorized list (like many of the search results I looked through), I assure you.

I have an SSH keypair that I generated on my laptop, however I wiped the hard drive to install a different Linux distro (Xbuntu 18.04.1 LTS). I have the public and private keys and the keyphrase saved on a online password manager.

The public key is in the form:

```
ssh-rsa (base64 key) user@hostname
```

The private key is in the form:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,(hexadecimal number)

(base64 key)
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I import these into my new OS install? Either via GUI or CLI?

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am misunderstanding the question, the solution is to add them to your user’s `~/.ssh/` directory on the new machine.

First, create that `~/.ssh/` directory — if it doesn’t somehow already exist — like this:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
```

Now copy and paste that private key to the file `id_rsa` in `~/.ssh/` like this; using `nano` as an example but otherwise use whatever editor you like to use.

```
nano ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Paste it in there and save it.

For the public key, do something similar but for the file `id_rsa.pub` like this:

```
nano ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Now with that done, be sure the permissions for the `~/.ssh/` directory are `700` like this:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
```

And finally set the permissions for the key files themselves like this:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

The keys should now be set an usable. Attempt to connect to whatever host you use them with and you should be a prompt for the passphrase. Enter it and et voilà! It should be recognized and used.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Good catch. My bad. Fixed!